# How to convert to date format using R and whether weekend dates missing will be problem for Arima / Prophet forecasting model?

Tags: r, date, date-formatting, forecast

This is date format in data frame

```
'data.frame':   2663 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Date : chr  "25-Sep-20" "24-Sep-20" "23-Sep-20" "22-Sep-20"
```

How to convert to proper date format to apply Auto Arima or Prophet model?

Whether weekend dates or any date missing will be problem for Arima / Prophet forecasting model?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Manager sab, if there is missing date then it will impact your forecasting model.
if there is any missing date data treat it. Take mean,median,etc.. whichever is giving good accuracy keep it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `as.Date()`:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format = "%d-%b-%y")
```

To learn about conversion specifications, see [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strptime).